# getting a cell to reference itself (need it for conditional formatting)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

My spreadsheet involves highlighting cells that have values that are also found in a separate range.

When using a formula to apply a rule in excel im not sure if the syntax is the same. It says: "Format values where this formula is true"

So what i need to do is to make a rule that formats a cell if its value is present in a separate range, but it looks like i have to reference the cell itself to do that. Can anybody offer a solution to this?

Comment: you can use reference the cell you want to format.  So if the Cell is A1 and you wanted to test if it was equal to `2` the the formula would be `=A1=2`  In your case I would use `=COUNTIF(G:G,A1)>0` where G:G is your other range and A1 is the value to be tested.

Comment: im not sure if thats possible because the rule would apply to not just a single cell but many multiple ranges

Comment: So if you put the above formula and in the Applies To: box put A:A.  It will automatically adjust the relative reference of A1 to A2,A3,...